How to add a keyboard shortcut to a flatpak app without using .sh file?
I want to launch a flatpak app that I know it's binary but it doesn't launch. I tried flatpak run md.obsidian, /var/lib/flatpak/app/md.obsidian.Obsidian/current/active/files/obsidian but to no avail.
Adding a custom keyboard shortcut only requires running it from the binary. It is easy to identify it using which <app> if it is .deb, apt, or snap, but not for flatpak.
